# explode wp post title on homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

The homepage of my wordpress website contains last posts, which will be displayed on two columns, but I want to explode my post title into a bootstrap grid.

I have zero knowledge of php, but looking on tutorials i managed to write this code which only explodes a given title (string), and I would like to apply this code to all post titles from my homepage.

```
$title = "This is - an exploded - title";
$str = explode ("-", $title);
$p1 = $str[0];
$p2 = $str[1];
$p3 = $str[2];

echo "<div class='row'><div class='col-md-1'> $p1 </div> <div class='col-md-2'> $p2 </div> <div class='col-md-2'> $p3 </div></div>";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Bootstrap Grid</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<?php
$title = "This is - an exploded - title";
$str = explode ("-", $title);
$p1 = $str[0];
$p2 = $str[1];
$p3 = $str[2];

echo "<div class='row'>";
echo "<div class='col-md-1'>";
echo $p1;
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='col-md-2'>";
echo $p2; 
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='col-md-2'>";
echo $p3; 
echo "</div>";
?>
</html>
```